# Magento product import

Tags: php, magento, magento2

i want to programmatically import a product into my magento. Unfortunatly I get an error which is not telling me a lot maybe some of you have an idea. Here is my php code:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Create Product Model';
echo '</pre>';
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->setSku('my-sku2'); 
$product->setName('Sample Simple Product'); 
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); 
$product->setStatus(1); 
$product->setWeight(10); 
$product->setVisibility(4); 
$product->setTaxClassId(0);
$product->setTypeId('simple'); 
$product->setPrice(100);
$product->setStockData(
   array(
      'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
      'manage_stock' => 1,
      'is_in_stock' => 1,
      'qty' => 999999999
        )
 );
 try {
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
    echo 'PRODUCT SAVED ';
    return 'Saved';
 } catch (CouldNotSaveException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR COULD';
        print_r($e);
 } catch (InputException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR INPUT';
        print_r($e);
 } catch (StateException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR STATE';
        print_r($e);
 } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR LocalizedException';
    echo 'Something failed for product import ' . $product . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($e);
 }
```

The error that i get is

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Inchoo/Helloworld/Block/Helloworld.php on line 241

Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Inchoo/Helloworld/Block/Helloworld.php on line 241
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Inchoo/Helloworld/Block/Helloworld.php(241): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(4096, 'Object of class...', '/Applications/M...', 241, Array)
```

I don't have an idea what i am doing wrong. The first time when i let the code ran it was working.

**UPDATE**

When i remove the try catch part and just call

```
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

I get an error that 1 exception(s):

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Product with SKU "my-sku2" does not exist
```

And of course it does not exist because i want to create a new product. So how can i create a new product?

Comment: what are you using object manager or creating module?? or use similar question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/programmatically-create-a-simple-product-in-magento-2

Comment: Hello i am using a productfactory to create the product model.

Comment: Any update? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert the $product object to a string in the last try-catch's echo. I believe that is what your Exception message is pointing at. Try to remove the echo and see what the LocalizedException gives instead.

If you want to log $product data, you should consider using `$product->debug();` which returns an array of data without all the object recursion. The function can be used on any object extending `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DataObject.php#L468

**UPDATE**

In addition to above, for the `NoSuchEntityException` you experienced after removing the try-catch; I tried your code and received following error in admin "Please enter a value less than or equal to 99999999." on quantity, might have something to do with the problem.

If you're calling the create from frontend and your Magento is not in single-store mode, it might also be something fuzzy with the store ID. In that case, set `$product->setStoreId(0);` to make sure it's saving as it would in admin.

Comment: Hello Mattias thanks for your answer. I tried to set the storeID and change the amount of quantity but i still get the error of NoSuchEntityException. If i remove the echo from the LocalizedException i get also the NoSuchEntityException. I am still not sure what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are using productFactory to create the product model, why aren't you just saving it?

```
$product->save();
```

Comment: The `save()` function is deprecated on models in Magento 2 as they must not be responsible for their own persistence. One should always use a repository to save the model, or else you'll bypass data preparation and validation, ultimately risking to end up with faulty data in the database.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L645